# AWS Amplify can't access S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm trying to set up a small CI/CD using GitHub actions and AWS amplify for a series of small projects, I tried to use the Build from git in Amplify but for some reason, the site breaks the second time the site is built and deployed, so I decided to perform the build and artifact generation in GitHub Actions, so far everything works even the loading in the S3 bucket, but when I try to use the command for request a deployment it always returns

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedException) when calling the StartDeployment operation: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

I attached a role with S3 and amplify access to the app, but it still fails, I can make the manual update on the website or mark the artifact as public read, but I don't believe that's a good practice.

EDIT 1

S3 Bucket Policy

```
{
   "Sid":"Stmt1677734301706",
   "Effect":"Allow",
   "Principal":{
      "Service":"amplify.amazonaws.com",
      "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::USERID:role/AmplifyRole"
   },
   "Action":"s3:GetObject",
   "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::websites-builds/*"
}
```

Service role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "amplify.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

The service role has the AdministratorAccess-Amplify that is managed by Amazon, and I believe it gives access to S3 completely

Comment: `I attached a role with S3 and amplify access to the app` - I think role should be attached to amplify to access s3, because amplify has to perform operations on s3. 

And can you post your role and policy in your question so that its easy to understand why amplify is not able to access s3 bucket

Comment: @JatinMehrotra you're right I forgot to add the policies, there should be now, I tried adding the role to the service, but it still gives the same result access denied